# Proof with the definition of limit and derivative

Tags: calculus

I want to prove with the definition of limits and derivative that if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$$

then $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+1)-f(x) = 0$$

I can solve it with the Mean Value Theorem at $[x, x+1]$ but i don't understand how i must use the definitions. 
It's necessary to use only definitions.

Comment: Use Mean-Value theorem. Also, this has been asked multiple times here on MSE. Please search.

Comment: **Prove** is the verb, **proof** is the noun.

Answer (score 1):

By the existence of the limit of the derivative we know that $\;f\;$ is continuous in $\;[x,x+1]\;$ and differentiable in $\;(x,x+1)\;$ , so there exists $\;c_x\in (x,x+1)\;$ s.t.

$$f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x}=f'(c_x)$$

Now note that as $\;x\to\infty\;\;\;$ **also** $\;\;\;c_x\to\infty\;$ , so

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x)=0$$